# Jquery with datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

I'm using datable plugin (http://datatables.net/examples/) with pagination in my project. I have 5000 entries in my database.

How I can perform my data lazy loading? For example on the first pagination page load only 100 entries; on the second, another 100 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=251

Answer (score 1):

You can set the pagination trough the option "iDisplayLength":

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "iDisplayLength": 100
    } );
} )
```

Documentation:
http://datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayLength